# If error from jquery ajax call should be redirected to other jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

If error occurs in jquery ajax call i have to redirect to `error.jsp` in error block of ajax call. I have tried using following:

```
window.location = 'smpaError.jsp';
window.location.href='smpaError.jsp';
Window.open('smpaError.jsp', '_top');
```

First two gave `404` and last option didn't work.  When I tried giving `http://www.google.com` it worked.

Can any one let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: Seems some path issue. What is the location of your `smpaError.jsp` ?

Comment: Location is webapp\WEB-INF\views\smpaError.jsp . Url is coming as expected like  http://localhost:9080/${contextname}/smpaError.jsp

Comment: Have you tried with href= `"views\smpaError.jsp"` ??

Comment: yes, JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /views/smpaError.jsp

Comment: Hmm..Are you able to see the jsp page, directly from browser with full url ? Let me know the full url once. It must look like `http://localhost.././..jsp`

Comment: No, i am not able to see the jsp page but the url looks correct. the difference i can find is all other pages are displayed through contoller but I want to load this page directly .

Comment: If url is correct, you must see the jsp in browser :)

Comment: This is the URL: http://localhost:9080/smpaWeb/views/smpaError.jsp,

Comment: Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /views/smpaError.jsp

Comment: So, the file you are referring is not at that location right ? If you are not able to see from browser, that means you cannot able to see from code as well. Cam you try to get the correct path ? Or a screenshot of your path structure ?

Comment: hmmm..seems like URL is not correct..let me check..Thanks :)

Comment: That is what I'm trying to convey :) You are welcome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a path issue with you jsp. As you mentioned in comments, the file is in difference folder. So that you need to give the url as

```
window.location = '/folderStructerHere/smpaError.jsp';
```

Comment: Does jquery load serve my purpose or any other alternative.

Comment: Actually we should not redirect user to another page from a AJAX web application. That kills the UX of user. Even in ajax load, you need a div to show the entire JSP. I don't think it is a clean way. Showing a one line error message on top or in a customized pop up is a better way.